# Papyrus: "Unreferenceable element" error

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

I made a class diagram model a few months that I have been using for code generation. Some days ago the code generator started hiccuping, I ran the validator again and a series of errors like this is one are now showing up:

> Unreferenceable element: model::Simulation View::Protected

The past few days I have been trying to figure what this is about, but in vain. There is no obvious error in the model and the search engine turns up zero results for the error message.

**Update**: This issue is now [reported as a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438955).